# how to remove compositor frame time window in inspect element tool of chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am getting an overlapping window in my inspect element tool. It is quite disturbing. Is there any way I can remove it?

I checked the settings to disable the tool but couldn't find. Even google din't help.[image]

The box I'm talking about is at the top right corner. It pops up only when I click inspect element in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open Dev tools
2. Press Escape
3. Go to rendering panel
4. Uncheck *Enable continuous page repainting* and *Show FPS meter*